# WebAPI routing without parameters?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I would like to set up routing so that I can use two different Get methods on the same controller.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public bool IsServerRunning()
    {
        return true;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string GetVersion()
    {
        return typeof(IVRLookupController).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
    }
```

The default route is

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This will route will throw and error that two methods fit the route. How do I set up routing to handle these two methods?

Answer (score 1):

You could add the Action to your route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```